# A string in a python function's parameter list

Tags: python, ray

In [this project](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/b4c527b3f3e61bbea72b15706a9958fd337c93a6/rllib/agents/dqn/apex.py#L100), I encounter code like the following

```py
def update_prio_and_stats(item: ("ActorHandle", dict, int)):
```

I know that this specifies that the argument passed to `update_prio_and_stats` should be a tuple of `("ActorHandle", dict, int)`. The `dict` and `int` are easy to understand -- they are built in type. But I'm confused about the string `"ActorHandle"`, which, I guess, should specify a [ray actor](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/walkthrough.html#remote-classes-actors). How does this work out?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: I know that the tuple specifies the desired type for the argument as the link you provided explains. What I'm confused about is the str `"ActorHandle"`.

Comment: It is a new type or a user defined type. Read NewType section. So ActorHandle is a type defined somewhere in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ActorHandle" is a reference to class name created in cpp/include/ray/api/actor_handle.h in that project (custom data type)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this mean that we can specify a class name using a string like the above one in python?

Comment: if it is a Python class - no quotes are needed. String is used when referring to C classes.